# Treeview Getting parentNode xaml wpf

Tags: wpf

I have a treeview in wpf and I load it ok is all done in zaml .
I have a problem and this is mainly because I am new to zaml.

If i have this structure

```
    England
      London
      Manchester
      Liverpool
      etc...
```

and I select london i need to display "England-London" .
I dont seem to get how to retrieve the parent of the selected child.

Can you help?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add SelectedItemChanged event to your TreeView and use this code:

```
private void yourTreeView_SelectedItemChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<object> e)
    {
        if (sender is TreeView && ((TreeViewItem)((TreeView)sender).SelectedItem).Parent != null)
        {
            TreeViewItem parent = (TreeViewItem)((TreeViewItem)((TreeView)sender).SelectedItem).Parent;
            //do your stuff here
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.Tried that but crashes on the first line when selecting the root node.
Also is it possible to do it in xaml?
thanks for your help